# Express pre remove triggers another pre remove on remove

Tags: javascript, api, express, npm, mongoose

Let's say I have 4 models like so:

```text
┌────────────┐      ┌────────────┐
│    User    │      │    Goal    │
├────────────┤ 1    ├────────────┤ 1
│    _id     │◄──┐  │    _id     │◄──┐
└────────────┘   └──┤  ref_user  │   │
                1..*└────────────┘   │
                                     │
┌───────────┐     ┌───────────────┐  │
│   Date    │     │     Data      │  │
├───────────┤ 1   ├───────────────┤  │
│ _id: date │◄─┐  │     _id       │  │
└───────────┘  └──┤    ref_date   │  │
                1 │    ref_goal   ├──┘
                  └───────────────┘ *
```

I created a `pre remove` when deleting a data it automatically removes the date associated.

```
DataSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
    try {
        await DateModel.findByIdAndRemove(this.ref_date);
        console.log("Date removed");
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
});
```

The issue I am facing is that when I remove a goal, I want all the Data associated to be deleted (it works) BUT I want the DataModel.remove to triggers its `pre remove` and remove its Date.
In a logical perspective, when removing data on the `pre remove` hook in Goal, this also should trigger the `pre remove` in Data since Data data are removed. Why when removing a data from another `pre remove` hook it doesn't trigger its `pre remove` ?

From Goal, I can retreive an array of Data, but I don't think that looping through the array and removing one by one the date is a good practrice.

Is there a way to triggeres the pre remove from Data, from the pre remove from Goal ? Or a way to remove all the Date from an array of Data ?

ps: in the futur, I want the same thing again when deleting a user (deleting all its goals that deletes all the data and the date).

Edit :

As requested, he is my goal pre-remove hook

```
GoalSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
    try {
        await DataModel.deleteMany({ 'ref_goal': this._id });
        console.log("Data removed");
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
});
```

I tried `deleteMany`, `remove`, etc. but none seems to trigger the `Data` pre-remove hook

Env:

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.12.2",
```

Comment: Can you show the Goal `pre remove` hook?

Comment: Which version of mongoose and express are you using?

Comment: And also add the schema/model definition for Date Data and Goal. Why not define date as a nested model in the Data scheme. As shown here? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: @Shasak I am new with react-native, I did not know about nested models. However the problems is the same if I want to remove a user, I want all its Goals to be removed, and all the data of the goals too. In the futur, my shema is going to be more complicated, I want to understand why pre remove hook do not trigger another schema pre remove hook

Comment: Did you have a chance to test my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your current code:

1. You're registering a `remove` hook on your `data` schema:

   ```
   DataSchema.pre('remove', ...)
   ```

   while you're `goal`'s `remove` hook's callback [triggers](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.deleteMany) a `deleteMany` middleware:

   ```
   await DataModel.deleteMany(...)
   ```

   hence `data`'s `remove` hook is not triggered.

   Now, you mention that you tried other functions, such as `remove`, which takes us to the second issue:
2. You're registering `remove` hooks on documents (that's the default), while executing functions on models.

   See this note on the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html):

   > **Note**: If you specify `schema.pre('remove')`, Mongoose will register this
   > middleware for `doc.remove()` by default. If you want to your middleware
   > to run on `Query.remove()` use `schema.pre('remove', { query: true, document: false }, fn)`.

   Of relevance is also this explanation:

   > You can pass options to `Schema.pre()` and `Schema.post()` to switch
   > whether Mongoose calls your `remove()` hook for `Document.remove()` or
   > `Model.remove()`. Note here that you need to set both `document` and `query`
   > properties in the passed object:

   > ```
   > // Only document middleware 
   > schema.pre('remove', { document: true, query: false }, function() {   
   >    console.log('Removing doc!'); 
   > });
   >
   > // Only query middleware. This will get called when you do `Model.remove()` 
   > // but not `doc.remove()`. 
   > schema.pre('remove', { query: true, document: false }, function() {  
   >    console.log('Removing!'); 
   > });
   > ```

I think the following should work:

```
const onRemoveData = async function (next) {
   try {
        let removed = [this];
        if (this instanceof mongoose.Query) {
           removed = await this.model.find(this.getQuery());
        }
        removed.forEach(function(doc) {
            await DateModel.findByIdAndRemove(doc.ref_date);
            console.log("Date removed");
        });
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
}
DataSchema.pre(['remove', 'deleteMany'], { document: true, query: false}, onRemoveData);
DataSchema.pre(['remove', 'deleteMany'], { document: false, query: true}, onRemoveData);
```

Comment: Thank you, now the data pre remove is triggered but `this` is now a `Query` and I don't find how I can the the `this.ref_date` in the data hook

Comment: In the `onRemoveData` function, `this` is a `Query {...}`. How can I access `this.ref_date` ?

Comment: You're right, as the docs note: "If you need to access the document that will be updated, you need to execute an explicit query for the document." I editted the code to make it work, please try it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your correction works almost perfectly, it deletes only one `Date` I think because of `this.model.findOne`. I tried with `this.modal.find` but it doesn't delete any `Date`. I read the documentation, it only talks about `this.model.findOne`

Comment: Oh right, `find` returns an array. I editted again, please try it (note I also enclosed `[this]`).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but `async function (err, doc)` makes `doc` values `0` for the first element. (I tried with 3 elements, the loop prints 0, 1 then 2). So `doc.ref_date` is `undefined`

Comment: Use `function (doc)` instead. Code editted.

Comment: I figured that out, thank you verry much. Sorry bothering you like that but I am new to this techno